# How to declare json data fields that I am getting in an api in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

[image]

As can be seen from the image, I am getting error lines under element.url etc. from line no. 62. I am fetching data from news api and in result I am getting json response which looks like this. I am passing these title, description etc. from api response to another component in my react app as props.

[image]

Now the error says this :

> any |
> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

So my question is; is there a way I can declare the rest of the fields of the json data so my editor doesn't give this error? Here is my code....

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        articles: [],
        totalResults: 0,
        loading: false,
        page: 1,
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    let apiKey = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=7e87c89bfbbd4b8b8bb0721d45a6d454&pageSize=18&page=${this.state.page}`;
    let data = await (await fetch(apiKey)).json();
    this.setState({ articles: data.articles, totalResults: data.totalResults });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container my-4">
            <h2 id="heading">Top headlines of the day</h2>
            <div className="row my-4">
                {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="col-md-4 mb-3" key={element.url}>
                            <NewsItem
                                title={element.title}
                                description={element.description}
                                imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
                                more={element.url}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
```

Comment: Where do you declare `this.state` and what type information do you provide in that declaration?  Please include code and error messages *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).

Comment: The editor is giving you a TypeScript error, but you are writing JavaScript code. Do you care about TypeScript errors? Your code is correct as is, and should work without issue. If you do care about TypeScript errors you will need to convert your code to TypeScript and then type the `articles` object: `type Article = { title: string; ... }`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes I am writing javascript and my code is working fine. But ignoring errors is not a good practise that's why I asked. I don't know why I keep getting typescript errors in js files...

Comment: @BittuJoshi: It's not really a question of "ignoring errors".  TypeScript performs type checking at build time, and provides syntax for specifying type information at design time.  But you're not actually *using* any of that.  Which begs the question... Why are you using TypeScript if you're not *using TypeScript*?  You'd either stop using it entirely and stick to JavaScript, *or* you'd use it fully and write TypeScript code.  Which one are you looking to do?

Comment: @BittuJoshi it seems that you are using VS Code. You should be able to turn type checkin of JS off: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript

Comment: If you do find the (inferred) type checks helpful, but want to turn some off on a line-by-line basis, you can put the comment `// @ts-ignore` above the line and it will ignore TS errors for that line